# What guarantees that the inverse of every element in a subgroup, is also in the subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H \subset G$. $H$ is also a subgroup under the same operator as $G$ if and only if:

- closed under the group operation: $u, v \in H$, then $uv \in H$
- closed under the application of inverse: $uu^{-1} = e \in H$

So due to closure under the application of inverse, we know that $e \in H$. So, for some $u \in H$, $u^{-1} \in H$ (trivially, we know that $e \in H$ and $e^{-1} = e \in H$). But, what guarantees that for all $v \in H$, $v^{-1}$ also in $H$? Shouldn't there be a third requirement apart from the closure requirements guaranteeing the existence of an inverse for every element in $H$?

Comment: the second condition: being closed under inverses means if $u \in H$, then $u^{-1} \in H$. What you have written as the second condition is incorrect.

Comment: For a finite group, the closure condition is sufficient.

Comment: @Joffan not quite - you still need an extra assumption.

Comment: @DerekHolt OK, what is that assumption?

Comment: You need $H$ to be nonempty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second condition isn't correct. The actual second condition is that the inverses are contained in your subset (as you understand is required). This, along with closure, ensures that the identity is in there as well.

Comment: It doesn't guarantee that the identity is there as well without an extra assumption.

Comment: I see your statement about nonempty above. This is of course true. There's no discussion to be had about empty subsets.